ActiveMQ Classic on Ubuntu 22.04 on VM starts but immediately exits
This installation was done on my KVM/Ubuntu by apt install, but I had the same problem after installing via download and unzipping everything in /opt and setting up the service file, etc.  When I use systemctl start activemq it actually shows "active" but immediately exits, proven by system status activemq. When I run /usr/bin/activemq start I get similar results. I think perhaps there is some strange permissions problem that stops it from creating the PID file but that is a guess from this rookie to Linux. Will post output from each below.
This is the tail of what I get when running activemq start. I suspect the final line exit $RET not found, but I'm in over my head to know what it means:
/var/lib/activemq/conf:/var/lib/activemq/../lib/:
"-Dactivemq.home="/usr/share/activemq"               
-Dactivemq.base="/var/lib/activemq/"               
-Dactivemq.conf="/var/lib/activemq/conf"               
-Dactivemq.data="/var/lib/activemq/data" -jar "/usr/share/activemq/bin/activemq.jar" start >> /dev/null 2>&1 &
              RET="$?"; APID="$!";
              echo $APID > /run/activemq.pid;
              echo "INFO: pidfile created : '/run/activemq.pid' ****(pid '$APID')";exit $RET: not found****


I suspect this LOG4J output that "pidfile created". It does not exist in /run.
Now this is what I get when I try to start as a service. systemctl start activemq produces nothing visible, but systemctl status activemq shows the problem of how it "exited" after starting:
activemq.service - LSB: ActiveMQ instance
     **Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/activemq; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2024-03-30 19:34:39 CST; 24h ago
     **Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
     CPU: 21ms

Mar 30 19:34:39 working-virtual-box systemd[1]: Starting LSB: ActiveMQ instance...
Mar 30 19:34:39 working-virtual-box activemq[16412]:  * Starting ActiveMQ instance  activemq
Mar 30 19:34:39 working-virtual-box activemq[16412]: No instances found at /etc/activemq/instances-ena>
Mar 30 19:34:39 working-virtual-box systemd[1]: Started LSB: ActiveMQ instance.


I tried running the script as root as root seems to own everything. Nada.
I tried adding activemq user to my admin group. Nada.
Since it starts and then exits it seems reasonable to ask what process might fail AFTER it starts?  This is the black box for me.

I also have Ubuntu 22.04 and I ran sudo apt install activemq. When I run activemq start or activemq console I also see failures like you. I also tried sudo activemq start and sudo activemq console which failed. It's also worth noting that version 5.16.1 was installed which is quite old and suffers from CVE-2023-46604. This package is not maintained by Apache, and at this point I would recommend against using it.

FWIW, I don't have any problems running the broker if I just download it from the Apache website.

I suspected that old version syndrome, Justin. So, I downloaded the latest version manually, unzipped it, did the thing with the service file, etc. and that failed the same way the old version failed. I have nothing to lose by uninstalling and then trying another download, but Einstein used to say that trying what fails over and over again is a sign of lunacy,  Hoping that maybe botched some configuration the first time.

Found solution (Justin, good guess that it was a stale version):  removed the stale version and then downloaded the tar.gz file for Artemis2.33.0.  Bingo, problems solved. Broker instance runs fine in a terminal or as a service.  Well, at least they started, har.

Without warning the activemq service just stopped and refuses to start again!  This is after it ran successfully yesterday. I can still run the broker for my new instance, so not all is lost.  But I cannot start the service for love nor money, either with "systemctl start activemq" nor with its own script in my broker-instance bin with command "sudo ./activemq-service start"

That information certainly isn't enough to diagnose your problem. If you found a solution to your original question (which you indicated previously) then you should post an answer, accept it, and then post a new question. If you haven't found a solution then you should modify your original question to explain the issue you're currently facing or delete it and post a new question. In any event, you need to provide more details so folks can actually help.

The question was mostly answered by uninstalling the ActiveMQ installed by apt on Ubuntu22.04, and then installing Artemis2.33.0.  The latter seems to be compatible.  That being said of the three Artemis startup options only two would work initially.

Sorry but this webapp really doesn't like edits to comments today. Horrible.  I never finished my other comment because it keep freezing the browser.  Whatever, using the Artemis scripts in ../../myinstance/bin worked, but the "systemctl start artemis" still failed.  Solution was to add an "artemis.service" file to /etc/systemd/system.  This was not done because of the confusion of having worked/removed the older ActiveMQ.  Call it user-error, I think. Currently there is nothing that doesn't work, including "systemctle start artemis".  Case is closed AFAIK.

Whatever you did to solve your problem you should post that as an answer and accept it. If you have additional problems you should post new questions about those.

I cannot reproduce this problem using Artemis-2.33.0, and that included a lot of testing by:

userdel for user artemis. Artemis doesn't care.
chown user (from root to normal user) for all of the dirs and files for my broker.  Artemis doesn't care.
Introduce a typo to the artemis.service file. Adequate messaging.
Fixing typos in artemis.service and not running systemctl daemon-reload. Adequate messaging.
Typo in artemis.service file forcing it to use the artemis script instead of artemis-service script. Forget the message but I remember it as being adequate.
Forced reboot after introducing a typo or fixing a typo in artemis.service. The system handles it as any other normal edit.

In all cases Artemis handled all error conditions with adequate messaging. Never did I see any such problem as my original "start(exited)" problem. I can only conclude that the original problem cannot be duplicated when running Artemis on Ubunto22.04.
The problem for ActiveMQ 5.16.0 may have a fix by user (suspecting the service file) but at this point it's a non-issue for me.
